# Heap insert is unsorted

Tags: c, sorting, insert, heap, depth

I have a list of entities I want to render in C, and my render buffer uses heap insert each frame to make sure the entity depths render in order. However, for some reason, the heap always ends up unsorted. I've looked over the code dozens of times, had friends look over the code, and I just can't seem to find *why* the entities are always out of order. I'm hoping that maybe a fresh pair of eyes can help me see the error in my ways. Here's my commented code:

(Please note that x, y, z, and depth (unused here) are all stored as `int`s in the entity structs.

```
void AEC_RenderCatalogToBuffer(AEC_EntityCatalog* entityCatalog,  
                               AEC_SpriteBuffer* spriteBuffer)
{
    //The values we'll be using
    unsigned int heap_size = 0;
    unsigned int heap_at = 1;
    int frame = spriteBuffer->frame + 1;
    int x, y, z;
    int temp_depth;

    //Loop through all the entities
    for (int search = 0; search < AEC_ENTITY_COUNT; search++)  
    {
        // If an entity is drawable and it has an x, y, z,  
        // insert it into the buffer for rendering
        if (   entityCatalog  
               ->entity_components[search].component_mask[AEC_DRAWABLE]  
            && entityCatalog
               ->entity_components[search].component_mask[AEC_DISPLACEMENT])
        {
            //Prepare data for heap insertion
            temp_depth = AEC_GetIsoDepth(entityCatalog, search);
            x = entityCatalog->displacement[search].x;
            y = entityCatalog->displacement[search].y;
            z = entityCatalog->displacement[search].z;

            //Increase the heap size by 1, save the size as the end node
            heap_size++;
            heap_at = heap_size;
            spriteBuffer->is_filled[heap_at] = frame;

            // If the parent node is greater than 0,  
            // has a larger or equal y (depth)  
            // and is being drawn in the current frame
            while (   (heap_at - 1)/2 > 0  
                   && spriteBuffer->y[(heap_at - 1) / 2] >= y  
                   && spriteBuffer->is_filled[(heap_at - 1) / 2] == frame
                  )
            {
                spriteBuffer->entity[heap_at] 
                = spriteBuffer->entity[(heap_at - 1)/2];
                spriteBuffer->depth[heap_at] 
                = spriteBuffer->depth[(heap_at - 1)/2];
                spriteBuffer->x[heap_at] = spriteBuffer->x[(heap_at - 1)/2];
                spriteBuffer->y[heap_at] = spriteBuffer->y[(heap_at - 1)/2];
                spriteBuffer->z[heap_at] = spriteBuffer->z[(heap_at - 1)/2];

                heap_at = (heap_at - 1)/2;
            }

            // Place the new entity's information into  
            // the correct place in the array
            spriteBuffer->is_filled[heap_at] = frame;
            spriteBuffer->x[heap_at] = x;
            spriteBuffer->y[heap_at] = y;
            spriteBuffer->z[heap_at]= z;
            spriteBuffer->entity[heap_at] = search;
            spriteBuffer->depth[heap_at] = temp_depth;
        }
    }

    // Once all the entities have submitted their draw depth
    //  and have been sorted by y-index,  
    //  save the heap size and the current frame
    spriteBuffer->size = heap_size;
    spriteBuffer->frame = frame;

    printf("Checking: ");
    for (int q=0;q<heap_size+1;q++)
    {
        if (spriteBuffer->is_filled[q] == frame)
        {
            printf("%d ", spriteBuffer->y[q]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

How can I fix the heap insert??? Thanks!

Comment: I did not have a closer look at your code, but [Heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_data_structure) are not completely sorted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour,  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Consider referring to "binary heap" instead of just "heap". Maybe mention https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap to get answerers into the right context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary-min-heap you have implemented only guarantees that the parent of two children is smaller than both children (as @chtz has commented). But it does not guarantee that the left child is smaller than the right one.

For example, your heap could look like this (index:value):

```
    0:3
1:5     2:13
```

Printing in index order would give you 3,5,13. This happens to be sorted.
But the heap could also look like this and still be correct:

```
     0:3
1:15     2:13
```

What you might have intended to do, was to implement a binary search tree.
In such a tree (assuming unique values)

- the left  child is smaller than the parent
- the right child is bigger  than the parent

For example, when inserting (5,1,2,3,20,10,24,12) you would get a tree like this:

```
          5
    1           20
 _    2     10      24
_ _  _ 3   _  12   _  _
```

Note that such a tree is not compact in an array, it has often empty places "_".
If you want to do such a tree, you need to find the right place to add a new member, using the rules. Swapping upwards, as in a heap is not needed.
But in order to print a binary tree, it must be traversed. Print recursively, first the left child, then the parent, then the right child.
Traversing the example tree would give:
_, _, _, 1, _, 2, 3, 5, _, 10, 12, _, 24, _
Obviously, it is necessary to keep track which node is actually used or empty ("_"); in contrast to a heap.

When choosing a tree structure of appropriate size,  consider the worst case, which is inserting sorted data.
For example, if you insert 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, you get:

```
               1  
       _               2  
   _       _       _       3  
 _   _   _   _   _   _   _   5  
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 10
```

So for handling N values you need `(2<<N)-1` places in the tree to be safe.
Or use a tree built from dynamically allocated memory with pointers.
If you hate the worst case (many people did), then have a look at self balancing trees.
E.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

Comment: Thank you so much, you're absolutely right. As soon as I saw @chtz's answer, I realized my huge mistake. I've been losing sleep over the wrong data structure. I'll make the change.        A binary tree array should be length 2n, right? I can implement that quite easily, I think...